# MySQL generate random number that depends on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been searching for few hours and I have no idea how to do this. The problem is next. I have two tables, customers and orders. **Customers** have id and 5-6 columns that are empty and have to be filled with random data. For this purpose, lets take `orders_accepted_campaigns` as column that we want to fill with data. In **orders** table we have customer_ids and order values. So how should I write a query that will fill each this `orders_accepted_campaigns` field with random number that is lower than number of orders that each customer has made (`count(customer_id) from orders group by customer_id`) so you can't have 4 orders and 5 `orders_accepted_campaigns`?

Comment: It's simple arithmetic. RAND() generates a number between 0 and 1. Multiply that number by the number of orders made.

Comment: I was hoping that it won't be something that trivial and "stupid" cause I've been trying for some time. Well, looks like it's time to go to sleep for me. Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I fear that would only magnify the stupidity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want an `update`:

```
update customers c left join
       (select customer_id, count(*) as cnt
        from orders o
        group by customer_id
       ) o
       on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
    set orders_accepted_campaigns = floor(rand() * cnt);
```

Note:  This sets the value to `0` when the customer has zero orders.

Comment: YES!! This is what I was looking for. Query that will update table with random number lower than some other value, in this case number of orders. You have just small tiny "error"; customer_id is missing in group by :). Thank you for help, I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an uniformly distributed random integer between 0 and `k`-1 inclusive, use this expression.

```
  TRUNCATE(RAND() * k , 0)
```

Avoid `CAST`; it rounds rather than truncates, which messes up the uniform distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your help, too but I was looking for something like @Gordon Linoffs answer, so I will accept his answer!